# Angle in qiskit

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms, qiskit, programming, entanglement

I have been working on Qiskit. Is it possible to display just the angle of each gate in a circuit as an output?

For example, if the below code is my circuit is it possible to just print the angle of the gate. We have function `QuantumCircuit.count_ops()` to display the gate counts similarly is there a way to do so?

```
q2 = QuantumRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q2)
circuit.cu1(math.pi/2, q2[0], q2[1])
print(circuit)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a built in function for this, but you can always hack a little to iterate over the gate list:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, QuantumRegister
import math
q2 = QuantumRegister(2)
circuit = QuantumCircuit(q2)
circuit.cu1(math.pi/2, q2[0], q2[1])
for gate, _, _ in circuit._data:
    print(gate.params[0])
```

However, instructions in Qiskit do not have a standardized interface, meaning not every gate will have `params[0]` set (e.g. x gate) or only one parameter (e.g. u3 gate). So it's really a question of which gates you are going to use in your circuit and knowing how their angles are represented in Qiskit (using `gate.defintion` might help).

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate over the circuit data as in [Gadi A's answer](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/11742/11908), and use gate.qasm(), then you get the gate printed in concise format with all the relevant parameters.

```
for gate in circuit.data:
    print(gate[0].qasm())
```